# splice repeated object from array vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Pokemon App that lets you add a pokemon to your 'pokedex'. It takes a pokemon object in this.$store.state.pokemon and pushes it to this.$store.state.pokedex. As a user can push the same object multiple times into the pokedex, I'm having trouble deleting objects from the pokedex using the traditional .splice(index, 1). It currently will delete the last item in the array, not the item it's called on. Is there a way to pass the key of the object to splice?

```
//Pokedex.vue
<template>
    <pokedex-card 
        v-for="(pokemon, i) in pokedex" 
        :key="`${i}+${pokemon.id}`"
        :pokemon="pokemon">
          <button @click="releasePokemon(i)">Release {{ pokemon.name }} ?</button>
    </pokedex-card>
</tempalte>

methods:{
    releasePokemon(id){
      this.$store.dispatch('releasePokemon', id)
    }
```

And the vuex store:

```
//index.js
REMOVE_FROM_POKEDEX(state, id){
      //find pokemon position in array by matching it's object ID
      var pokePosition = state.pokedex.map(pokemon => { return pokemon.id }).indexOf(id)
      state.pokedex.splice(pokePosition, 1);
    }
```

Comment: because the objects pushed to the pokedex are identical, they have the same ID. So using pokemon.id won't work, it just splices the last array item, because it matches the condition immediately. Neither of these suggestions work in this case

Comment: have you tried `state.pokedex.splice(id, 1)` in REMOVE_FROM_POKEDEX, because `id` in this method is actually the index of the element, not the id

Comment: yes, and it always removes the last item of the array instead of the item at that index position

Comment: There is no way to pass ID instead of index to `Array.splice()` method. If you want to use ID - you will first have to find the index of this ID yourself (e.g. by `Array.findIndex()` method) and then provide the `index` to `Array.splice()`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having a similar problem, I figured out I had to create a new object when pushing the pokemon item to the pokedex array, that I could create a unique reference number for:

```
state.pokedex.push( { ref: pokemon.id + state.pokedex.length, poke: pokemon } );
```

Then in the component where I rendered the pokemon in state.pokedex, I used the ref as the key:

```
<pokedex-card 
        v-for="pokemon in pokedex" 
        :key="pokemon.ref"
        :pokemon="pokemon">
</pokedex-card>
```

So in the store, I could delete the Object:

```
REMOVE_FROM_POKEDEX(state, id){
   let index = state.pokedex.findIndex(pokemon => pokemon.ref === id);
   state.pokedex.splice(index, 1);
}
```